# python - creating an empty file and closing in one line

Tags: python, file-io

I want to ensure that all resources are being cleaned correctly. Is this a safe thing to do:

```
try:
    closing(open(okFilePath, "w"))
except Exception, exception:
    logger.error(exception)
    raise
```

**EDIT:**

Infact, thinking about it, do I even need the try/catch as I am raising the exception anyways I can log at a higher level. If it errors on creating the file, one can assume there is nothing to close?

Comment: You can try to use "with" contex in python with filelike objects.

Comment: A 1 liner could be `open(okFilePath, 'w+').close() ` ?

Comment: @karthikr Except if `open` raises an exception, it won't be closed.  `with open(path, 'w+'): pass` can technically be expressed on a single line though, and that will handle exceptions.

Comment: Note that in python3.3 you can use the [`'x'` mode](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#builtin-functions-and-types) for creating a file or failing if it exists already/cannot be created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be sure that the file is closed in any case, you can use the [with](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) statement. For example:

```
try:
    with open(path_to_file, "w+") as f:
        # Do whatever with f
except:
    # log exception
```

Comment: What if I don't want to do anything with the file. I simply want to create it?

Comment: @Ben: Then leave the `as f` part out.

Comment: @Ben: ...and change the `# Do whatever with f` line to just `pass` _or_ put everything on one line `with open(path_to_file, w+): pass`.

Comment: I only partially agree with this answer because it is NOT a oneliner (okay, the `with ...: pass` is oneliner). You can do `open(path_to_file, "w+").close()` which opens (creates if not present) and then closes the file.

Comment: @rbaleksandar There is no advantage in writing code in one line. I personally don't understand this desire.

Comment: Iam pretty sure he wasnt asking about solution that is everywhere on the internet and is not oneline. Question was oneline to create empty file.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this to just create a file and close it in one line.

`with open(file_path, 'w') as document: pass`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be:

```py
open(fileName, 'w').close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`mknod` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mknod) creates a new file without opening it

```py
import os
import stat
os.mknod('test', 0o600 | stat.S_IFREG)
# 0o600 -> owner can read+write file, group and other have no permissions
# stat.S_IFREG -> create regular file, instead of character/block device, pipe, or other special file
```

Caveat: only available on Unix

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real one liner:

```
os.remove("echo > YourFile")
```

It will work on Linux and Windows.